# SQL ORACLE Creating a border with using htf (hypertext functions)

Tags: sql, oracle, plsql

I'm working on SQL ORACLE DATABASE and I create a table than going into foor loob and working with htf for convert table to html formate.

```
set define off

create table show_mail (id number, data varchar2(25));

insert into show_mail values(101, 'one hundred & one')
insert into show_mail values(202, 'two hundred & two')
insert into show_mail values(303, 'three hundred & three')

declare
v_html varchar2(32767);
begin
v_html := htf.tableopen;
for i in (select * from show_mail) loop
v_html := v_html || htf.tablerowopen;
v_html := v_html || htf.tabledata(i.id);
v_html := v_html || htf.tabledata(htf.escape_sc(i.data));
v_html := v_html || htf.tablerowclose;
end loop;
v_html := v_html || htf.tableclose;
dbms_output.put_line(v_html);
end;
```

I want to add this code border for each column and line. Also want to give a name for columns. Is that possible?

Comment: The htf functions are rather limited. You may have to put HTML code manually as plain string.

Answer (score 1):

[Documentation](https://docs.oracle.com/cd/E28280_01/portal.1111/e12042/pshtp.htm#YPREF290) says, that you can specify `cborder` parameter:

```
v_html := htf.tableopen('border="1px"');
```

Comment: Thank you so much. I read that a lot but couldn't understand how to use it. It helped a lot.

Comment: You're welcome. Please take a look at the various examples on the web, I found a few typing _"oracle htf.tableopen border"_ on Google.